# Spring beans used and injected if bean class does not have any getter/setter methods?

Tags: spring

[Here](http://www.shaunabram.com/beans-vs-pojos/) it is stated that Spring beans can be instantiated, configured and injected *even if bean class does not have any getter/setter methods*.

Is that true?

Could you give an example (or a link to such)?

> The reason Spring managed objects are referred to as beans is because
>   in the very early versions, Spring was intended only for use with
>   JavaBeans. That is no longer the case of course: **Spring can manage
>   just about any object, even if it doesn’t have JavaBean type
>   characteristics such as** default constructors or **mutator methods
>   (getters and setters).** None the less, the term ‘Spring beans’ has
>   stuck.

I get these exceptions:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException` caused by `org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'name' of bean class [com.my.pkg1.Student]: Bean property 'name' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?`

```
@WebListener
public class MyListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {   
        String metadata = "mybean.xml";
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(metadata );

        Student student = context.getBean("student", Student.class);
        System.out.println(student.age);
        System.out.println(student.name);       
    }   
}
```

and

```
public class Student {

    String name;

    int age;

//  public String getName() {
//      return name;
//  }
//
//  public void setName(String name) {
//      this.name = name;
//  }
//
//  public int getAge() {
//      return age;
//  }
//
//  public void setAge(int age) {
//      this.age = age;
//  }
}
```

and mybean.xml *bean definition* XML file for Student class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="student" class="com.my.pkg1.Student">
        <property name="name" value="John"></property>
        <property name="age" value="23"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I feel `<property name="name" value="John">` is not valid without getters and setters...

Answer (score 0):

since your bean definition sets the `name` and `age` properties, a setter is needed to assign those values.

You could also customize the bean using a constructor (`<constructor-arg>`) or a builder function (`factory-method`).

Here's an intro to these different construction methods: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-xml-injection